# PHP: Illegal string offset because [] binds tighter than ->

Tags: php, operator-precedence

I am fairly new to PHP and just had a learning experience that I am sharing here to help others who, like me, may need help to find the cause of this error and also because I still don't know what the solution is and am sure there is simply a syntax that I just haven't found yet to do what I need to do.

So, the problem can be demonstrated with something like this:

```
class Sample {
    protected $foo = array();
    public function magicSampleSetFunc($property, $key, $value) {
        $this->$property[$key] = $value;
    }
}
...
$s = new Sample();
$s->magicSampleSetFunc('foo', 'someKey', 'someVal');
```

Obviously, this isn't my real code (nor have I run it) this is just a minimal example to explain my situation.  Here we have a member variable foo that is clearly an array and a generic function that is going to try to set a key and value into it.  I can var_dump `$this->$property` and see that it is an array, but on the `$this->$property[$key]` line I get the error message: "Warning: Illegal string offset 'someKey' in ...".

At first I though it was saying that 'someKey' was an illegal string to use as an array offset, which didn't make sense.  And, even if I wrap it in an isset it complains.  The first thing I learned is that if you have a string in php, you can use the array access operator to get a character out of that string.  So the warning message is actually complaining that 'someKey' is not a valid offset into a string (because it is not an integer offset).  Okay, but I just var_dumped `$this->$property` and see that it is an array, so what gives?  The second lesson was one of operator precedence.  The array operator "[]" binds tighter than the indirection operator "->".  So, the binding of that statement is actually something like: `( $this-> ( $property[$key] ) )`.  So, it is illegally trying to offset the string in $property by the index in $key.  What I wanted was to offset the array in `$this->$property` by the index in $key.

So, now we come to my question.  The third lesson I need to learn, and haven't figured out yet is how do I override this operator precedence issue?  I tried `($this->$property)[$key]` but that appears to be a sytax error.  Is there some other syntax I can use to get the interpreter to understand what I meant to do?  Or, do I have to assign `$this->$property` to a temporary variable first?  If I do, wouldn't that mean that my actual member variable array is not updated?  Do I need a temp reference or something?  What's the right syntax for my situation here?  Thanks!

Comment: If it's not your real code, and you haven't run it, then how are you so certain it's representative of your issue? (Hint: it's not.) First post your real code and any error information, so we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Without seeing my real code, how do you know this is not representative of it?  My real code is many, many files whatever I post must be a summary of the real thing, and there is always the danger that I have mis-summarized.  I feel that this is an accurate summary of the code I am working with.  I invite you to answer according to the issue in this code and if that isn't my actual issue because I have mis-summarized then that is on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the way to do it: 
Your variable name is basically `{$property}` so when you do `$this->$property[$key]` I think PHP parser gets confused. I usually make sure that to explicitly state it to the parser that my variable name is $property which is done by using curly braces around variable.

Curly braces are used to explicitly specify the end of a variable name

```
class Sample {
    protected $foo = array();
    public function magicSampleSetFunc($property, $key, $value) {
        $this->{$property}[$key] = $value;
    }
}
...
$s = new Sample();
$s->magicSampleSetFunc('foo', 'someKey', 'someVal');
```

Comment: to clarify: the curly brackets are used for dynamically changing variable/function -names, in this case you want to output the contents of the $property variable in order to use it as the function name or class-variable name

Comment: aah.. agree .. for some reason I only read as "only function name" and no mention of class variable..

Comment: This does indeed solve the issue.  And, it kind-a makes sense to me.  I'm clarifying that `$property[$key]` is not the variable that I want to get my member name from.  The other part that I had missed is that "->" is not on the operator precedence list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).  When I saw "[]" near the very top I assumed it bound tighter than "->".  So, does "->" actually bind tighter?  Why isn't "->" listed on the operator precedence list -- isn't it considered an operator?

Comment: Oh, also, in the name of best practices, is it considered good PHP best practice to always put {} around your variable names?

Comment: "->" is called  T_OBJECT_OPERATOR and since it has no meaning until we know object has been initialized I believe the precedence is left to right.. but I think the error is not because of precedence but of how php interprets a variable. else if someone can correct me..